# Action which worked yesterday now does crashes

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Yesterday my Google Action worked perfectly, but today it is not. I did not change anything inside the code or Dialogflow.

It seems the very first intent, which is login/registration intent, works, since both console.log statements show up in the console. console.log('Test2') does not show up.
The last line in the logs is: "Function execution took 1265 ms, finished with status code: 200".

Could you help me out? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/07MyO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgYEO.png

```
app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", (conv, input) => {
  console.log('Test1a')
  conv.add(new SignIn('To gather your data.'))
    console.log('Test1b')
})

app.intent("welkomintent", (conv, input, signin) => {
  console.log('Test2')
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    conv.close('You cannot use this app without registration!');
 } else {
  conv.add('Welcome back!')
}
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Can I suggest that you not only post the code samples (that you did) but also describe the design that you are shooting for.  From what I can see, your welcome intent has a follow-up.  This means that a new context is created and the second intent won't be examined until a user interaction occurs following the welcome message.  Can you describe the path you are following over time.

Comment: You don't need to create a followup context for your welcome intent.

Comment: Hi Kolban, thanks for your message. This code is part of a quiz-app I am trying to make. However, the other code is not relevant for this problem since the Action throws an error somewhere between the Default Welcome Intent and intent it automaticaly redirects to (welkomintent). The default welcome intent indeed provides an output context which is the input for the second intent.

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for your feedback. Even when I delete the contexts, it gives me the same result.